# How to define multiple foreign keys referring to the same table in sequelize or sequelize-typescript?

Tags: regex, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

Defining model for TableC which is a mapping table for TableA and TableB. TableA contains composite primary key (id,globalVersion).So need to define these to fields inside the map table as foreign keys. Tried something as below but its not working.[sequelize-typescript and PostGres]

```
    @BelongsTo(() => TableA)
    id_fk: TableA;
    @ForeignKey(() => TableA)
    @Column(DataType.INTEGER)
    id: number;

    @BelongsTo(() => TableA)
    globalVersion_fk: TableA;
    @ForeignKey(() => TableA)
    @Column(DataType.INTEGER)
    globalVersion: number;
```

Comment: AFAIK Sequelize does not support composite foreign keys